# How to fetch the last batch of updates from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, date, sorting

I have the following data in a MySQL database table called `MyTable`:

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+
|    my_id | country_gb | date_updated        |
+----------+------------+---------------------+
|       10 |        224 | 2013-02-07 00:00:00 |
|       30 |        224 | 2013-02-07 00:00:00 |
|       40 |        299 | 2013-02-07 00:00:00 |
|       60 |        277 | 2013-02-09 00:00:00 |
|       70 |        222 | 2013-02-09 00:00:00 |
|      100 |        349 | 2013-02-09 00:00:00 |
```

How do I query the database so that only the rows with the latest date is returned?

I know I could do `SELECT * from 'MyTable' WHERE 'date_updated'="2013-02-09 00:00:00"`, but what if I don't now the specific `date_updated` (as I don't)?  I thought I could sort the table by date_updated DESC in one command (something like `SELECT date_updated FROM 'MyTable' ORDER BY date_updated DESC LIMIT 1`) and then use the `date_updated` value to do another search but I don't know how to do this all in one command or even if there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subquery

```
SELECT * from 'MyTable' WHERE 'date_updated'=(
    SELECT date_updated FROM 'MyTable' ORDER BY date_updated DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date_updated = (SELECT MAX(date_updated) FROM MyTable)
```